# vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties segfaulting

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, vulkan

I've started programming with Vulkan/C++ and have the Problem that the line `vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties( physical_device, &queue_family_count, nullptr );` is segfaulting.

`queue_family_count` is initialized and declared as `uint32_t queue_family_count = 0;` and `physical_device` is a `const VkPhysicalDevice` returned by `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices`.

Other functions requiring a `VkPhysicalDevice` such as `vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties` work, so the device seems to be valid.

`vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties` was loaded with `PFN_vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties
vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties = 
(PFN_vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties) vkGetInstanceProcAddr( 
instance, "vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties" );`

I don't know if it has to do with the operating system, so here is some info:
OS: Arch Linux
WM: i3-gaps,
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.17.2-1-ARCH

The name of the `physical_device` is: Intel(R) Haswell Mobile (only device returned by `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices`).

Comment: Which module segfaults? Do you use validation layers? Check if the previous commands did not return `VK_ERROR`. Which SDK, and driver version you are using? Perhaps show the whole code, or a `api_dump`.

Comment: Which module segfaults?
I'm very new and don't know what a module is? All I found googling are shadermodules, not relevant to creating a device.

Do you use validation layers?
I think so. If they output stuff on a successful run, then not.

Check if the previous commands did not return VK_ERROR.
They did not.

Which SDK, and driver version you are using?
SDK: 1.1.73.0
Driver: vulkan-intel 18.1.1-1

Comment: "module" is the `.dll`, or `.so`. It would be either the driver, or one of the layers.

Comment: It just magically fixed itself after a pacman -Syu. But thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed itself after a `pacman -Syu` today.